# Hive S3 data insert keeps overwriting the data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive, insert

Here is my scenario:

1. I load data from one of the folders in S3 bucket. Let's call this bucket 'new_data'.

   CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE new_data
   (col1 string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
   LOCATION 's3://some-bucket/folder'
2. Next, I load data from another folder in S3, let's call this 'data_already_imported'.

   CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE data_already_imported (col1 string)
   ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
   LOCATION 's3://some-bucket/another-folder'
3. Then, I find the difference between new_data and data_already_imported

   CREATE TABLE difference AS 
   SELECT * FROM 
   ( 
    SELECT n.* FROM new_data n 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN data_already_imported old 
    ON n.col1 = old.col1 
    WHERE old.col1 IS NULL
   ) i;

Now, I want to move this 'difference' into data_already_imported folder. Currently I have

```
INSERT INTO TABLE data_already_imported 
SELECT * FROM difference;
```

The problem is this overwrites the data that was already there in data_already_imported. NOTE: I have tried it with `INSERT OVERWRITE` as well. Could someone please point me what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hive, there no such a thing as appending records to an already populated table. You have to create another table (let's say it will be called `new_data_already_imported`) then do something like:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE new_data_already_imported
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM data_already_imported UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM difference );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply larsen. This is what I had in mind but just wanted to check if there was a way to append records. Anyways, accepting the answer. Thanks!

Comment: It is actually possible to append records by manually adding files to the HDFS directory containing the table (probably something like `apps/hive/warehouse/table_name`). You have to be careful doing this, especially if partitions are involved, or you could seriously mess up your table. Go with larsen's solution unless you absolutely need the performance.